# Prevent Fancybox from showing images

Tags: javascript, fancybox

how can I prevent Fancybox from showing certain images? I have a select button, where a user selects a data-color attribute, which each "a" tag in the fancybox gallery has.

http://jsfiddle.net/brq5b/1/

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
    beforeShow: function() {

        var selectedColor = $("#colorForm").val();
        if(selectedColor != 'all') {
            formData = $(this.element).parent().data('color');
            formData = formData.split(' ');
            for (var i in formData) {
                if (formData[i] == selectedColor) {
                    alert("ok");
                }
            }
        }  
    },

    afterLoad : function() {
        this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
    }
});
```

For now it just alerts "ok".

If you select "yellow", it shows the thumbnail which has data-color attribute yellow, but then it opens the gallery and it says image 3 of 3. I want it to show just one.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a long time I came up with a solution. On every change of the select button I remove the fancybox class from every a tag, which does not correspond to the color selected in the select button.

http://jsfiddle.net/brq5b/2/

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#colorForm').on('change', function () {  
        var selectedColor = this.value;  
        if(selectedColor != 'all') {
            hrefItems = $('#fancybox-thumbs a');

        hrefItems.each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('fancybox')) {
                $(this).addClass('fancybox');
            }
            formData = $(this).parent().data('color');

            if(formData.indexOf(selectedColor) == -1) {
                $(this).removeClass('fancybox');
            }

        });

    }
    else {
        hrefItems = $('#fancybox-thumbs a');
        hrefItems.each(function() {
            if(!$(this).hasClass('fancybox')) {
                $(this).addClass('fancybox');
            }

        });
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

});